# Qpcr negative efficiency

Tags: microbiology, pcr

Hello Stack Exchange Biology world,

I have struggled with my qPRC results for over 5 months. I have a bunch of DNA samples, and I want to find the quantity of *Pseudomonas syringae* contained. My issue was the extremely high efficiency (sometimes even 1200%) after the run. So, I decided to make everything from scratch. I used a **new set of primers** and a **new qPCR kit** ([kapa sybr fast qpcr master mix (2x)](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/deepweb/assets/sigmaaldrich/product/documents/418/169/sflckb.pdf)), and **I switched the sterilized double-distilled water** from the water filters in the lab to an ampoule one (to eliminate any contamination).
I incubated the bacteria again. I measured the OD=0.998A, before extracting this `DNA` (via NucleoSpin Soil, Mini kit for DNA from soil) with the following quality as `193μg/mL, 260/230 = 2,41 & 260/280=1,89`, which seems high quality.

For the standard curve, I did dilutions of 1:10, 1:100, 1:1000, and 1:10000 using the proportion of 5μl of DNA with 45μl SDW from the ampoule.

So now I have everything new and a "high quality of DNA" to work with. Yesterday, I attempted to perform a qPCR (SYBR green), and the **efficiency was -100%.** What should be wrong at this time? Is it something that I can change in my 20μl reaction?

```
SD Water from ampoule 7μl
QPCR Master Mix 10μl
Primer F 0,3 μl
Primer R 0,3 μl 
ROX high 0,4 μl
DNA 2μl
```

The machine I performed the reactions on is the `Thermo QuantStudio 5 Real-Time PCR`. Below, I am providing the experimental details as well as the qPCR results.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions to help me fix this issue.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Normally, if your qPCR efficiency was negative 100% I would say your dilutions were made properly just entered into the software in reverse order. But your amplification curves are pretty funky. How are you setting the threshold? And what is the baseline determination?  What about the melt curves? The protocol is strange too, in that it's taking multiple fluorescence readings per cycle. I wonder if that's screwing with the baseline readings. Typically just one measurement is taken after annealing/extension. Have you tried a 2-step protocol (deleting the 79C step)?

Comment: @MikeyC Thank you for your response. As I'm learning qPCR, I combined the KAPA SYBR® FAST Master Mix with a P. syringae protocol I found.  https://journals.asm.org/doi/10.1128/aem. The main issue was that the protocol used a different qPCR mix and annealing at 54°C compared to KAPA SYBR®(annealing at 60°C). I adjusted accordingly, but perhaps incorrectly. About the threshold and baseline determination, I used default settings. For my next run, I will only keep step 2 for fluorescence reading as recommended. Any further suggestions for refining my experimental method will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Run some of the qPCR results on a gel or have a look at the melt curves - you might well have more than one product being generated. Your std curve should have a little over 3 cycles between each point (copy number doubles each cycle so 3 cycles is 8x more copies to reach Ct) and the replicates should be quite tight. How long is the PCR product? It shouldn't need extension if it is <100 bp.

Comment: @bob1 I did, and you are absolutely right. Indeed, I have two zones on the curve amplicon. How do you know that? Wow, I am just surprised. Does it mean that my primers were not extended correctly? The primer sizes are 194 and 162 bp.

Comment: @KGee It was a suspicion (MikeyC noted it too), experience is a great tool... Your primers are 194 bp and 162 bp each? Or are those the amplicon sizes? Primers should only need to be about 18-25 bases for a highly specific reaction. The manual for the Kapa pol says extension of products less than 400 bp should need 1 second.

Comment: @bob1 Oh, I didn't get that (MikeyC) mentioned double zones. Obviously, you are an expert user. :) Do you recommend adjusting step 3 from 3 to 1? Will this extension fix the issue of the double zones? The f primer is 194 (22 bases), the R one is 162bp (20 bases), and the amplicon size is about 150bp. Thank you again!

Comment: Ah, I see - the primers are called "194" and "162". The sizes 20 and 22 are fine. You should go and optimize the binding of the primers in the Kapa mix; it might well be different to in another system.  A 3-step is fine. The Kapa manual says  *For 3-step cycling protocols, anneal at optimal annealing temperature
for 20 sec followed by the minimum time required for data acquisition
at 72ºC according to instrument guidelines)*  So you should acquire only at extension and for the minimum capable on your instrument. You'd need to check the instrument manual for this information.

Comment: @bob1 Oh, I see. Thank you once again for the response. Let's see. Then I hope to "get rid" of double zones this time  :P!!!